# Renderscript Intrinscics methods within a custom .rs file on Android

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript, android-renderscript

is it possible to call ScriptIntrinsics methods within a custom .rs file on Android? What I'd like to achieve is to convert a video frame from YUV to RGBA ,then apply gaussian blur.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for feedback but I already found a solution with using the `ScriptGroup.Builder` to instantiate multiple scripts in one chain.

```
        // Create a group YUV->RGB + Blur chain
        ScriptGroup.Builder b = new ScriptGroup.Builder(rs);
        b.addKernel(scriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.getKernelID());
        b.addKernel(scriptIntrinsicBlur.getKernelID());

        // Connection is on RGBA8888 side
        b.addConnection(rgbTypeBuilder.create(), scriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.getKernelID(), scriptIntrinsicBlur.getFieldID_Input());
        mScriptGroup = b.create();

        // Set output
        mScriptGroup.setOutput(scriptIntrinsicBlur.getKernelID(), mOutputAllocation);
        scriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.setInput(mInputAllocation);
```

Then just call the `mScriptGroup.execute()` to make it run as needed.

Comment: Oh thank you for posting this solution, I didn't know about ScriptGroup

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a script inside a rs file to my knowledge, but what you can do is call the scripts one after another using the output allocation for the first script as the input allocation for the second, this should give you the expected results